# Calculate average from some EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my activity, there are two buttons: one for adding an item to a ListView, which is formed by an EditText (where the user enters a decimal number) and another one, which will start the calculation. The goal is to calculate the average of the numbers entered in the EditTexts, depending on the number of items added to the ListView.

My problem is that I've got the following code, and I don't know how to calculate the average. I was thinking about dividing the total by i, but it gives me an error.

```
void addNumberFromText()
{
    double total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<MarkListView.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View wantedView = MarkListView.getChildAt(i);
        markresult = (TextView)wantedView.findViewById(R.id.subjectmark);
        double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.getText().toString());
        total+=value;
        markresult1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.average); 
    }
    Log.d("PersActivity","total sum is "+total);
    markresult1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.average);
    markresult1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    markresult1.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
}
```

Is there any solution? I have no ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Which adapter are you using for the ListView?

Comment: I'd recommend you to do the reference to the Views inside of onCreate(). Here you are doing it inside of a Loop, which is bad.

Comment: @bhargavg I'm using an ArrayAdapter

Comment: @LuisAlberto thank you, but I'm new to Android development. How should I do that?

Comment: I'd help you, but you'll have to ask a new question, so i can help you, due if i answer your question, maybe people will downvote my answer cuz the answer will be out scope of this question.

Comment: @LuisAlberto thank you so much! I hope you have a solution. Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463273/average-from-edittexts